# Functional and performance testing for the “Finacle - Infosys” core banking system using IBM Rational

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing

I am trying to evaluate the capabilities of the below IBM Rational tools to handle functional testing automation and performance testing for the "Finacle - Infosys" core banking system.

1. IBM Rational Functional Tester (RFT)
2. IBM Rational Performance Tester (RPT)

Also, I would like to confirm whether any additional components are required to be added for both tools to support my testing needs (e.g. plugin to test web services or handling Oracle NCA JInitiator ... etc.).

Note: I apologize for posting the question twice on the "Software Quality Assurance and Testing" and the main "StackOverFlow" sites.

Comment: With my above question, what I am trying to understand whether RFT and RPT respectively support functional and performance testing over the "Finacle - Infosys". I am not trying to look for alternative testing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As checked and confirmed with IBM representatives and according to IBM Portal (Link [Here](http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/gsd/solutiondetails.do?solution=25721&expand=true&lc=en)), the use of both Rational Performance Tester (RPT) and Rational Functional Tester (RFT) should be supported.

We will have a project running to conduct both functional testing automation and performance testing for the "Finacle - Infosys" core banking system during the coming 12 months, after-which I can post any updates on this question of mine.

Answer (score 5):

I have no doubt that the IBM Rational tools could allow you to automate functional and performance testing.  However, there are many free and open source tools that also provide the same (or often better) functionality.  From my own experience working with proprietary test tools such as Rational (my experience was with Rational years ago, Silk and a bit of QTP) I would say that in general you get more support and faster turn-around using non proprietary solutions such as Selenium and JMeter.  There are also a lot more people using those tools, so finding information online is easier.

Selenium is pretty much the standard for web UI automation.

For performance testing of web sites and services JMeter is one option, or if you have a Visual Studio Ultimate install and licenses the Visual Studio Load Testing is what I prefer especially if the sites or services are hosted on Windows boxes.

Comment: I understand that both RFT and RPT respectively support functional and performance testing, however, I have no experience in "Finacle - Infosys", specifically the technology used to implement the clients (pure HTTP and web forms, Oracle JInitiator or NCA ... etc.). This question was to confirm whether both RFT and RPT can be used for testing over the "Finacle - Infosys".

Comment: Ah, it seems like you might have better luck looking in the Finacle - Infosys documentation or asking on their forums.  An educated guess would be that RFT and RPT support testing a service or application built upon "Finacle - Infosys".  If it is a web site/service then I'm sure it would.  If it's a windows application then it probably would, but I'm not familiar enough with the technologies to say definitively.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely RFT and RPT can be used to do functional and performance testing of Finnacle. I have worked with a couple of teams doing exactly the same.

I know this question is dated but would you be able to share the results of your usage here ?